# Single Catch Block for Multiple Methods in a Class java

Tags: java, class, optimization, exception

I have a class with static Methods for Handling MemCache Requests, it has different methods with different arguments.

Whenever Some method is called in that class,i want to increment totalRequest Counter and if Exception occur in any of the methods inside the class i want to increment a failed counter. Is there any way to do it ?

If being Static in Nature has some problems, let me know ? Also It should be a efficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use AOP. If you use [Guice](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AOP) or Maven it's quite easy to put in place around your beans. You'll declare an interceptor, that Guice or Maven will wrap around your methods.

There is also [AspectJ](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-aspectj/) but I have never used it.

Finally, you could wrap your calls in a caller method. With Java 8 and lambda, it would be something like this:

```
protected <T> T callWithTrace(Supplier<T> fn) throws Exception {
  //some code before the call
  try {
     T output=fn.get();
     //code after normal exec
     return output;
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
     //code in case of error (increase counter??)
     throw e;
  }
}

void someOtherMethod() {
   Object ret = callWithTrace({ () -> callToYourDangerousMethod()});
   Object ret = callWithTrace({ () -> callToAnotherDangerousMethod()});
}
```

With Java 7, you could also do it with anonymous inner classes, but it would be hard to read.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Could you please provide some link on AOP,  how to acheive this with a simple example, Which one would be preferable for real project ?

Comment: I have read the link, It was very helpful , As i am working on a real project, Implementing Guice will be a very costly task, and may be I can't used it at this point of time !

Comment: Is there any other Way to do it ? May be some design patterns which i can achieved without much dependecies changes.

Comment: , Added a lambda solution